# Is it possible to make a standalone React.tsx project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm still a student so this might be a stupid question.

For a school project we need to make a programm that does some speciffic stuff related to boats.
the programming language we all feel most comfortable with is React.tsx but we where wondering if it's possible to make a standalone programm( so not in a browser) in React.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React.tsx itself is not a programming language. React is rather a library and the programming language you use is Javascript (Incase of `.tsx` it's TypeScript)

If you are already familiar with React you can try **React Native for Windows + MacOS**. It helps you create Native Apps with React.

- https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows
- https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use electronJS
https://www.electronjs.org